# I want to disable any of Pivot's Headers

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to disable a `Pivot` item's header according to the conditions.

```
<Pivot>
    <Pivot.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="PivotHeaderItem">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="false"/>
        </Style>
    </Pivot.Resources>
    <PivotItem Header="Header1" IsEnabled = false>
        <!-- Something Content -->
    </PivotItem>
    <PivotItem Header="Header2">
        <!-- Something Content -->
    </PivotItem>
    <PivotItem Header="Header3">
        <!-- Something Content -->
    </PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```

- `<PivotItem IsEnabled = false>`

  - When I did this, the header and content of this PivotItem was disabled.
- `<Style TargetType="PivotHeaderItem"><Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="true"/></Style>`

  - When I did this, all the headers were disabled.

I thought I should find the `PivotHeaderItem` in the Pivot and set `isEnabled` to false, but I can't find it.

What should I do?

Comment: When trying to reproduce, I am not even able to disable a `PivotItem` by setting `IsEnabled = false`. Could you maybe share a bit more of your code?

Comment: Sorry, I added the code.
Please try again.

Comment: I have tried your code and I am still not able to disable the pivot items. I have experience with this being a thing, and always just removed the `PivotItem` from the `Pivot` when I wanted to disable it.
What I also know is that the `PivotHeader` does not have an `IsEnabled` property. Could you maybe explain why you would only want to disable the header while keeping the content of the `PivotItem` enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I thought I should find the PivotHeaderItem in the Pivot and set isEnabled to false, but I can't find it.

For your scenario, we suggest you implement Pivot with mvvm model and give class model a bool property to manage `PivotHeaderItem`. if you want to disable it you could hide it.

**For example**

```
<Pivot
    x:Name="MyPivot"
    Title="EMAIL"
    Visibility="Visible">
    <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <PivotItem>
                <Frame x:Name="PivotItemContent" />
            </PivotItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Pivot.ItemTemplate>

    <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding HeaderContent}" Visibility="{Binding IsEnable}" />           
        </DataTemplate>
    </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
</Pivot>

public ObservableCollection<Model> Items = new ObservableCollection<Model>() { 
    new Model{HeaderContent="One",IsEnable= true }, 
    new Model { HeaderContent = "Two", IsEnable = false },
    new Model { HeaderContent = "Three", IsEnable = true }, 
    new Model { HeaderContent = "Four", IsEnable = false } };

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();         
    MyPivot.ItemsSource = Items;
}
```

**Model class**

```
public class Model:ViewModelBase
{
    private bool _isEnable;
    public bool IsEnable
    {
        get { return _isEnable; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _isEnable, value);
        }
    }    
    public string HeaderContent { get; set; }
}
```

If we want to disable specific `PivotHeaderItem` we just need to find the matched and set IsEnable property as false.

```
Items[0].IsEnable = false;
```

**Update**

For pivot control without mvvm binding. we could use [`KeyTipTarget`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.keytiptarget?view=winrt-19041) to get PivotHeaderItem, then set it disable.

```
var item = (PivotItem)TestPivot.Items[0];
var keyTipTarget = (PivotHeaderItem)item.KeyTipTarget;
keyTipTarget.IsEnabled = false;
```

Comment: In the code you gave me, the header has disappeared.


`I changed Visibility="{Binding IsEnable}"` to `IsEnable="{Binding IsEnable}"`.

The header is not disabled.


However, your answer gave me a hint of a solution.

I found that changing `MyPivot.items[0].KeyTipTarget.IsEnabled` to false makes the header unselectable.


It's not good code, but now I can change the IsEnabled of the header.

`var item = (PivotItem)MyPivot.items[0];

var keyTipTarget = (PivotHeaderItem)item.KeyTipTarget;

keyTipTarget.IsEnabled = false;`


Thank you very much for your answer.